# selenium chrome driver, receive a "data:," in the URL and doesn't open correct webpage

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am using Chrome version 62 and Selenium webdriver v3.13.1
I have tried all the Chrome drivers that is compatible with Chrome v62 but yet I still receive the same issue. I can't update the Chrome version as the administrator at work(on a work pc) had prevented me to do so. Are there any alternatives to fixing this issue? Also I made sure the URL I wanted to access had "http://" in the code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What I did was to download MicrosoftWebDriver from

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

I placed the file inside the C:/Python37/Scripts folder and used Edge instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Edge()
browser.get("https://www.codewars.com")
```

I know it's not the same but it works! Hope you find it helpful.